# Why do the closed sets generate the same $\sigma$-algebra as the open sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ a topological space. How can I show that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the class of open subsets of $X$ (say $S[U]$) is the same as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the class of closed subsets of $X$ (say $S[C]$). I don't know how to start with the problem. If $A$ is in $S[U]$, how will $A$ look? Do I have to use $\sigma$-algebra technique here? If yes, can you give me some start?

Comment: You show that with every closed set you can generate every open set, and the other way, and it's all.

Comment: Why not just use the fact that sigma-algebra is closed under complements? So that from the set of open sets, you can get all closed sets. And from the set of closed sets, you can get all open sets.

Comment: @NazimJ got it! Thanks.